# graphql-java integer as an input

Tags: java, graphql, token, lexer, graphql-java

I am using

```
compile group: 'com.graphql-java', 
name: 'graphql-java-tools', 
version: '5.2.4'

type Query {
sampleQuery(roll : Int!) : SampleResponse
}
```

When I am trying to access this as given below in java

```
{sampleQuery(roll : ?2){samples{roll,name}}}
```

It gives 200 success response instead of 400 error response (as we are trying to pass invalid value in the input).

Here, the integer input accepts the values like `?2 or .2 or '2 or *2 or /2` etc...

Why does it accept it?
What can I do to validate this input and throw error saying invalid input param?
Is this an issue from graphQl implementation itself?

In the console logs I do get

```
line 2:72 token recognition error at: '?'
```

but I also get correct response for it. Ideally, this should not return valid response as the input itself is invalid.

**The main question is why don't graphQL validates integer input; rather it parses the input(discards the characters along with the digits)? It should strictly accept only the integer values and nothing else.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error handling with graphql-java-tools and graphql-spring-boot-starter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62085033/error-handling-with-graphql-java-tools-and-graphql-spring-boot-starter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as per the graphql grammer, it allows(parses) the integer value appended with some characters(tokens) (like ?,~`/*...etc) But it does not allow the punctuators like @,&,$,!,{,],[,|, etc.
Therefore, 200 success response is received and error is not thrown in this case.

**Reference:**
https://spec.graphql.org/draft/